# Как управлять начертаниями одного шрифта с помощью CSS?

Tags: css, шрифты

Я скачал шрифт, у которого есть много разных начертаний(около 15), но дело в том, что все начертания представлены 1 файлом в формате ttf. У каждого начертания есть свое название, но из-за того что все находится в 1 файле, я не могу прописать каждый шрифт с помощью @font-face. Подскажите есть ли решение, или же все таки придется скачивать каждое начертание отдельно?

Comment: Этот вопрос, видимо, уже решен: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47219679/how-can-i-include-different-font-weights-with-one-font-file

Answer (score 0):

Вариативные шрифты http://css.yoksel.ru/opentype-variable-fonts/

> ...Вариативные шрифты — это расширение формата OpenType, которое позволяет хранить все варианты начертаний в одном файле, а для переключения между ними использовать не только фиксированные шаги, но и промежуточные значения.

Answer (score 0):

Это даже все упрощает.

Пропишите `@font-face` один раз, указав ваш файл, а начертания, представленные в нем, задаются свойствами `font-family` и `font-style`.